# Show logged in user info in react-native drawerNavigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I've been searching for a simple solution with best practices to have drawer that would show user's info, i.e. name, age, etc. The login will happen in a separate screen but after the login is done, somehow user info should be passed to drawerNavigator.
DrawerNav
  - StackNav
    - Screen1
    - Screen2
  - SettingsScreen (login will happen here)

It's really frustrating that I couldn't find a working solution yet.
Expo code: https://snack.expo.io/@alisalimi25/user-info-drawer

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  Button,
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  Text,
  View
} from 'react-native';

import {
  createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator,
  DrawerItems, NavigationActions
} from 'react-navigation';

class Screen2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View><Text>Screen2</Text></View>
    );
  }
}
class Screen1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Screen1</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
          title='Open Drawer' />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

class SettingScreen extends React.Component {
  loginUser = () => {
    console.log('We need to pass user info into drawer navigator');
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Settings Page</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.loginUser()}
          title='Login' />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: Screen1,
    Screen2: Screen2
  }
);

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => {
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <Text>Hello USER_NAME_FROM_PROPS?</Text>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  )
};

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    StackNav: {
      screen: StackNav,
    },
    SettingScreen: {
      screen: SettingScreen
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
  }
);

export default DrawerNav;
```

I'm sure the solution is somewhere but I couldn't find it yet. Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I managed to use screenProps to pass around parameters between pages but I'm not sure if it's a good pattern because it's like global variables and I think there is a chance of name collision between different layers of navigation. The working code is:
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Button,
      SafeAreaView,
      ScrollView,
      Text,
      View
    } from 'react-native';

```
import {
  createDrawerNavigator, createStackNavigator,
  DrawerItems, NavigationActions
} from 'react-navigation';

class Screen2 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <View><Text>Screen2</Text></View>
    );
  }
}
class Screen1 extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
        <Text>Screen1</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
          title='Open Drawer' />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

class SettingScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    console.log('passed props for settingScreen are: ', props);
  }

  loginUser = () => {
    console.log('We need to pass user info into drawer navigator');
    this.props.screenProps.userId = 'Gandalf';
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
        <Text>Settings Page</Text>
        <Button
          onPress={() => this.loginUser()}
          title='Login' />
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const StackNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Screen1: Screen1,
    Screen2: Screen2
  }
);

const CustomDrawerContentComponent = (props) => {
  console.log('props in custom component are: ', props);
  return (
    <ScrollView>
      <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }} forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
        <Text>Hello {props.screenProps.userId}</Text>
        <DrawerItems {...props} />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ScrollView>
  )
};

const DrawerNav = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    StackNav: {
      screen: StackNav,
    },
    SettingScreen: {
      screen: SettingScreen
    }
  },
  {
    contentComponent: CustomDrawerContentComponent
  }
);

class DrawerNavWrapper extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loggedInUser: {

      }
    };
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <DrawerNav screenProps={this.state.loggedInUser} />
    );
  }
}

export default DrawerNavWrapper;
```

After "Login" button is pressed in SettingScreen, screenProps is set
    this.props.screenProps.userId = 'Gandalf';
and when you open drawer, "Hello Gandalf" will be shown.

The other solution is to use JS Modules.
Or maybe use react context (https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/4511)

Anyone knows a better solution?

Thanks